# Concurrency with scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder

Tags: scala, concurrency, spdf

I'm using [sPdf's run method](https://github.com/cloudify/sPDF/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/github/cloudify/scala.spdf/Pdf.scala#L13) to render HTML as a PDF file.

`run` uses `scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder` and it's `!` method:

```
/** Starts the process represented by this builder, blocks until it exits, and
    * returns the exit code.  Standard output and error are sent to the console.
    */
  def ! : Int
```

My controller is using a `Future` to asynchronously execute the conversion but won't spdf block all other interim executions?

```
 Future { pdf.run(sourceUrl, outputStream) } map { exitCode =>
     outputSteam.toByteArray
 }
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your answer [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1212596/paul-draper) did a little test and yeah looks to be that way :)

If I update sPdf's run like so:

```
  def run[A, B](sourceDocument: A, destinationDocument: B)(implicit sourceDocumentLike: SourceDocumentLike[A], destinationDocumentLike: DestinationDocumentLike[B]): Int = {
      println("start/ " + System.currentTimeMillis)
      < ... code removed ... >
      val result = (sink compose source)(process).!
      println("finish/ " + System.currentTimeMillis)
      result
  }
```

and I execute three consecutive requests the stdout prints

```
start 1461288779013
start 1461288779014
start 1461288779014
finish 1461288781018
finish 1461288781020
finish 1461288781020
```

Which looks like asynchronous execution.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` blocks the execution thread, not any other system thread (there's no locking happening) - but the real answer depends on how `spdf` works. If it lets multiple processes start up at once, then no blocking ought to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `Pdf#run`:

```
  def run[A, B](sourceDocument: A, destinationDocument: B)(implicit sourceDocumentLike: SourceDocumentLike[A], destinationDocumentLike: DestinationDocumentLike[B]): Int = {
    val commandLine = toCommandLine(sourceDocument, destinationDocument)
    val process = Process(commandLine)
    def source = sourceDocumentLike.sourceFrom(sourceDocument) _
    def sink = destinationDocumentLike.sinkTo(destinationDocument) _

    (sink compose source)(process).!
  }
```

There's no synchronization that prevents parallel execution. Assuming that the `ExecutionContext` has enough available threads,

```
Future { pdf.run(sourceUrl, outputStream) } map { exitCode =>
    outputSteam.toByteArray
}

Future { pdf.run(sourceUrl, outputStream) } map { exitCode =>
    outputSteam.toByteArray
}
```

will execute in parallel.

---

If instead, the `run` method had been, say, surrounded by a `synchronized` block, only one invocation would execute per `Pdf` instance. But there's no reason to prevent concurrency here, so the author didn't.